# Dirty read в однопоточном приложении java

Tags: java, hibernate, transaction

Есть два метода A() и B(), которые вызывают метод update(). Все методы @Transactional.
Приложение однопоточное, но столкнулся с проблемой что во время работы одной транзакции, вторая считывает данные старые (dirty read), ловил `nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)`. Пробовал read committed, такая же ситуация. Использовал saveAndFlush для принудительного обновления данных, такая же ситуация. Дополнительно попробовал накинуть serializable уровень, теперь ловлю `HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement]` это конечно же связано с тем, что отменяется обновление, которое в очереди, что можно сделать ?

Из вариантов было явный вызов exists перед методом update()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему используя lock(), слушатели паралельно пытались вызвать метод